# Why "my @variable" inside a sub and modified by sub/sub behaves so strange

Tags: perl, scope, subroutine

I have a strange behaved (to Python programmer) subroutine, which simplified as the following:

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
sub a {
  my @x;
  sub b { push @x, 1; print "inside: ", Dumper(\@x); }
  &b;
  print "outside: ", Dumper(\@x);
}
&a;
&a;
```

I found the result is:

```
inside: $VAR1=[ 1 ]
outside: $VAR1 = [ 1 ]
inside: $VAR1=[1, 1]
outside: $VAR1= []
```

What I thought is when calling `&a`, `@x` is empty array after "`my @x`" and has one element after "`&b`", then dead. Every time I call `&a`, it is the same. so the output should be all `$VAR1 = [ 1 ]`.

Then I read something like named sub routine are defined once in symbol table, then I do "`my $b = sub { ... }; &$b;`", it seems make sense to me.

How to explain?

Comment: Modern Perl seldom uses the `&` in front of a function name.

Comment: I just want to make &$b and &b, &a consistent. & in "&$b" is not optional if "my $b = sub { ... }". Anyway, so far just learned Perl for a month.

Comment: If I add `use warnings;` (or use `-w` on the command line), I get the message: `Variable "@x" will not stay shared at sub23.pl line 8.`.  Reminder: always use both `use warnings;` and `use strict;` (unless you know enough about Perl not to need that — I've only been using it for 20+ years so I know I don't know enough to risk it).

Comment: "*I've only been using it for 20+ years*" lol :-) I've been using Perl for 15 years but that result still surprise me!

Comment: Almost a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048248/variable-foo-will-not-stay-shared-warning-error-in-perl-while-calling-subrout/4048277#4048277

Comment: Side note: it is unusual to see a named sub inside a named sub. If this is real production code, you probably want to reconsider your approach

Comment: N.B. `&b` or `&$b` without `()` are a special form of sub call that you almost never want to use.  Do `&b()`/`&$b()` instead (or, as preferred by many, `b()`/`$b->()`).  (This does not apply to method calls; empty parentheses can be left off those.)

Comment: For sub inside sub, I kind of like this "local" define, used once and discard. Did not realize such a different behavior between named and anonymous subroutines.  @Zaid why not in production code ? are you saying "*named* sub inside a sub", but instead using "anonymous sub inside sub" is OK ?

Comment: @ForestYang that's right, if it is a use-and-throw type of situation, there is little reason to give the inner sub a name, `my $s = sub { ... }; $s->();` is a more natural choice here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the "perlref" man page:

> named subroutines are created at compile time so their lexical
>   variables [i.e., their 'my' variables] get assigned to the parent
>   lexicals from the first execution of the parent block.  If a parent
>   scope is entered a second time, its lexicals are created again, while
>   the nested subs still reference the old ones.

In other words, a named subroutine (your `b`), has its `@x` bound to the parent subroutine's "first" `@x`, so when `a` is called the first time, `b` adds a `1` to `@x`, and both the inner and outer copies refer to this same version.  However, the second time `a` is called, a new `@x` lexical is created, but `b` still points to the old one, so it adds a second `1` to that list and prints it (inner), but when it comes time for `a` to print its version, it prints out the (empty) brand new lexical (outer).

Anonymous subroutines don't exhibit this problem, so when you write `my $b = sub { ... }`, the inner `@x` always refers to the "current" version of `a`'s lexical `@x`.

Comment: Dumping `@x` before and after the call to `b` shows this up.

Comment: Printing out the address of `@x` (`print \@x` => `ARRAY(0x0bac0b17)` will also demonstrate this.