# Perl code giving strange error

Tags: perl

```
use Person;

print(" object creation ");
my $object = new Person( "Mohammad", "Saleem", 23234345);

print (" here after");
allthis();

sub allthis()
{
  print(  $object->getFirstName() );
}

if(1)
{ 
  print(" object creation ");
  my $object = new Person( "Mohammad", "Saleem", 23234345);
  allthis();

  sub allthis()
  {
    print($object->getFirstName());
  }
}
```

Person is defined here:

```
package Person;

sub new
{
  my $class = shift;
  my $self = {
    _firstName => shift,
    _lastName  => shift,
    _ssn       => shift,
  };
  print "First Name is $self->{_firstName}\n";
  print "Last Name is $self->{_lastName}\n";                                                  
  print "SSN is $self->{_ssn}\n";
  bless $self, $class;
  return $self;
}

sub setFirstName {
  my ( $self, $firstName ) = @_;
  $self->{_firstName} = $firstName if defined($firstName);
  return $self->{_firstName};
}

sub getFirstName {
  my( $self ) = @_;
  return $self->{_firstName};
}
1;
```

This leads to

> Error :
>    Can't call method "getFirstName" on an undefined value at check2.pl line 22.

The error won't occur in two cases:

1. declare the variables as `our`.
   example: `our object;`
2. rename one of the function names:
   `allthis` to `allthis1`

Can any one explain the reason?

Comment: Taking a glance, why `if(1)`? There's absolutely no reason for that to be there.

Comment: i was trying to recreate one of the issue .. in which there will be a if loop and inside it function gets defined... so i was trying that ... but any how.. any idea  why it is getting that error

Comment: ha ha ..alright ... if block ... i hope i am right this time ... :)

Comment: And you call subroutines before definition

Comment: if i remove if block code .... the code works, so subroutine definition place wont matter i feel

Comment: `use strict;` and `use warnings;` they will show you what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, all named subroutines are globally scoped.  You can't have two subroutines with the same name existing in two different scopes like that.  Thus, the second definition of `allthis()` overrides the first one.  You never use the first `allthis()` sub.

Further, because subroutines have access to the lexical variables of wherever they were defined, your first call to `allthis()` attempts to access the second `$object`; however, this hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: Also, I should have mentioned that switching to an `our` declaration means that you would only have one copy of `$object`.  It would act as a global variable within the scope of the current package, thus removing the error.  However, in that case a second use of `our` within the `if` statement would be meaningless, as you are merely referring to an already existing variable.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `use strict` and `use warnings`. Always. Each and every single time.

Because if you had, you would've received a warning that you were redefining `main::allthis()`.  So, don't do that.

This code should get you what you need:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Person;

print(" object creation ");
my $object = new Person( "Mohammad", "Saleem", 23234345);


sub allthis() #have to define after $object is created
{
print($object->getFirstName());
}

print (" here after");
allthis();

print(" object creation ");
$object = new Person( "Mohammad", "Saleem", 23234345);
allthis();
```

However, I'd consider whether it is necessary to use `$object` as a global variable (with respect to `allthis()`, and instead have your subroutine take an argument:

```
sub allthis
{
  my $object = shift;
  print $object->getFirstName();
}
```

Then, you'd call it via `allthis($object);`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i know that we should use strict and warrnings. can please tell me, why it works when i define the variables "our".

Comment: By this post, i am not expecting coding guidelines.... I am expecting an answer for the question, why the program work fine when i declare the variable "our $object = new Person( "Mohammad", "Saleem", 23234345);". so that i know, how perl actually works.

Comment: because then the first our $object and the second refer to the same variable.  only the second allthis function is ever called, and it binds to the second $object declaration; with my, that is a different $object than was set before the first allthis call.

Comment: but you hardly ever need to worry about how perl does variable binding in more complex cases; just pass what you need into functions instead of referring to outside variables.

Comment: @ysth: thanks for the reply. it make sense. but i dont understood, with "my" it goes out of the scope. can you please elaborate more or point me to some document which talks more on this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845060/what-is-the-difference-between-my-and-our-in-perl

Comment: seeram: named functions are global; you can only have one at a time.  when the code is compiled, the second allthis replaces the first.  The second allthis is in the lexical scope of the second $object lexical variable, and that hasn't yet been set at the time it is first called

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Person;

print(" object creation\n");
my $object = new Person( "Mohammad", "Saleem", 23234345 );


sub allthis() {
    print( $object->getFirstName() . "\n");
}

print(" here after\n");
allthis();



print(" object creation\n");

$object = new Person( "Mohammad", "Saleem", 23234345 );

allthis();
```

**Output:**

```
 object creation First Name is Mohammad
Last Name is Saleem
SSN is 23234345
 here afterMohammad
 object creation First Name is Mohammad
Last Name is Saleem
SSN is 23234345
Mohammad
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but i dont want to change the code. i mentioned two point in the post. when it passes and fails... so can please answer to those questions. i am not searching for code changes.. i know what to do , to make my piece of code work. but my intension of the post it to get answer for the questions of those two poins i mentioned in the post.