# Using global variables with strict pragma in Perl

Tags: perl, global-variables, strict

I was wondering if I could use some globals variables while using strict pragma.

For example, I've tried to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

sub print_global{
     print "your global is: $global\n";
}

$global = 1234;     #or even my $global = 1234;

print_global;
```

But as you can notice it doesn't work.

Are there any ways to define global variables when using strict pragma? (if any, of course)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just declare the global before using it:

```
our $global;
```

Unlike `my`, this does not create a new variable, but rather makes the variable available in this scope. So you could safely have code like

```
sub print_global{
     our $global;  # does not create a new variable like `my` would
     print "your global is: $global\n";
}

our $global = 1234;

print_global;
```

Comment: Please, say me what you intend for creating: declaring or defining?

Answer (score 1):

Declare `my $global;` above your function and it'll work with `use strict;`.

Comment: Yeah, it works. But didn't my keyword modified scope between functions? Why is my $global also visible to other subroutines declaring it above?

Comment: variables declared with `my` in most outer scope are visible to all below code regardless if in subroutine or not.

Comment: Ok but, how is it possible the example above?

Comment: check `my` vs `our` and how they actually behave http://stackoverflow.com/a/885888/223226

Comment: `our` variables always reference the fully qualified package variable `${__PACKAGE__}::VariableName` which is not lexically scoped like a `my` variable. What is lexically scoped is the alias `$VariableName`.

Comment: Thanks to both. I had forgotten that my variables are only scoped to the enclosing block and that you can define subroutines everywhere in the code.

Answer (score 1):

`use strict;` tells Perl you wish to be forced to declare your variables, and you did not do so. Add a declaration where appropriate.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $global;     # <----

sub print_global{
     print "your global is: $global\n";
}

$global = 1234;
print_global;
```