# Are there any differences between our defined variables and normal global variables in Perl?

Tags: perl, strict

Is the `our` modifier only used when strict pragma is active to let using global variables or is it even used for some extra features different from normal global variables when strict is off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `our` declarations can have additional features when compared with undeclared globals. But these are largely irrelevant.

`our` creates a lexical alias to a global variable (of the same name). That is, in `package Foo`, `our $bar` and `$Foo::bar` refer to the same variable. However, the former is only available in a tight lexical scope.

As `our` has a lexical effect, the alias can also shadow lexical variables with `my`:

```
our $foo = 42; # give some value
my  $foo = -1; # same name, different value
say "my  gives $foo";
our $foo;      # reintroduce the alias; shadow lexical
say "our gives $foo";
```

If you strip the `our` declarations and run it without strict, this obviously won't give the output

```
my  gives -1
our gives 42
```

Just like `my`, `our` can take a bit extra declaration syntax, e.g. *attributes*:

```
use threads::shared;
our $foo :shared;
```

You can also specify a type for usage with the `fields` pragma:

```
our Foo $foo;
```

This can't be done for global variables without `our`.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the [perldocs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html), `our` creates an alias to a package variable with the same name as the `our`ed variable **in the current package**.

If you're writing code that has multiple package definitions in it, you could use an `our`ed variable to pass an aliased variable between modules.

```
package Foo:
our $bar = 42;  # $bar is an alias for $Foo::bar

package Baz;
print $bar;     # prints '42', since $bar is $Foo::bar
```

Thus, a usage that has nothing to do with global variables.

Comment: All package variables are global variables.  What this use demonstrates is there is a purpose to `our` apart from satisfying `strict`.

Comment: According to the following question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845060/what-is-the-difference-between-my-and-our-in-perl) our variables are said to be package and global variables. I don't know who believe.

Comment: @none: There is no conflict here. `our` declares (an alias for) package (global) variables.

Comment: I have navigated half dozen similar questions in Stack Exchange and twice that in answers, and you're the first one that actually explains it in a way I could understand.

Answer (score 2):

Global, package variables are accessible anywhere, whether `strict` is in place or not, if you specify the fully-qualified name, i.e. you prefix it with the package name. So I can access `$main::variable` anywhere at any time.

Without `strict`, if you access `$variable` that you haven't declared with `my`, Perl assumes it is a package variable in the current package. `our` can be used to explicitly declare a package variable, but without `strict` it doesn't do much as anything undeclared behaves the same way.

With `strict` in place, variables declared with `our` are accessible using their local name as well as their fully-qualified name, in the lexical scope where the declaration appeared. That means that to access a global variable from two subroutines you must either declare it within both subroutines or declare it before both of them at an outer scope.