# Local and Global variables in perl

Tags: perl, scope

I am having few doubts about the `local/our` scope in Perl. I read a lot of documentation, but I am still in confusion is there. Following are the confusions

1. What is `local` scope?

   what I read is -> local copies the value of global variable, change the value, user will use it and outside the block it will retain the global value

   Confusion -> `my` does the same thing. Only benefit I see is that some variables like `$package::var` cannot be declared with my scope but can be declared with local scope. What else for local
2. What is "global" variable?

What I read is -> Its scope is within the package. Basically we put the global variable in `@EXPORT` array and use it or append the namespace with it to use in other packages.

I doubt -> Again if we declare variable with `my` scope in main only then we can access the variable throughout the package. Is that right? Is it possible to add the `my` scoped variables in `@EXPORT` array and use it in another packages?

I think global variables are declared with `our` keyword. Is there any other way to do so?

This question may look repetitive, but I am confused.

Comment: Kevin : How to highlight that. like my our all keyboards are highlighes

Comment: Put single quote marks (`) around the word to highlight.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845060/what-is-the-difference-between-my-and-our-in-perl

Comment: Questions about Perl variable scoping may be a bit repetitive, but it's very important. Perl variables are extremely difficult to understand. Much of it has to do with Perl's long history as it went from a mere hackish replacement for `awk` and `sh` and turned into a full object oriented language. At one time, all variables were package variables, and `local` was how you limited their scope. Now, we have three different variable types (don't forget `state`!), and this `local` function that doesn't really make local variables.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In terms of scoping, there are three kinds of variables in Perl.

- Lexical variables are lexically scoped, which means they are only visible in the current lexical scope (basically file or block).
- Package variables, on the other hand, can be used using their qualified form (e.g. `$Foo::x`) from anywhere in the interpreter, and they can be used without qualification by any code that shares the variable's package.
- Certain package variables are visible without qualification anywhere in the interpreter. These include punctuation vars and a few named vars such as `@ARGV` and `STDOUT`. For example, `$x` refers to `$Foo::x` when in package `Foo` and `$Bar::x` when in package `Bar` (assuming no lexical var named `$x` is in scope), but `$_` always refers to `$::_`.

Variables are destroyed when they are no longer referenced.

- Lexical variables are usually destroyed when the lexical scope is exited.
- Package variables are usually destroyed when the program exits.

Here are ways to create variable.

- `my` and `state` create a lexical variable.
- `our` creates a lexical variable that is aliased to the variable of the same name in the current package. In other words, `our $x;` is equivalent to `my \$x = \$Foo::x;` when in package `Foo`.
- Package variables are created on use.

`local` doesn't create any variables. It simply backs up a variable until the current lexical scope is destroyed. It is restored from its backed-up value at that point.

---

> `my` does the same thing.

No. `local` does not change the scope of a variable. While a lexical variable is only visible in a lexical scope, a localized package variable is still visible across the entire interpreter.

```
$x = 123;
sub foo { print "$x\n"; }
{ local $x = 456; foo(); }  # 456
foo();                      # 123
```

```
$x = 123;
sub foo { print "$x\n"; }
{ my $x = 456; foo(); }   # 123
foo();                    # 123
```

---

> What else for `local`

`local` is primarily used to approximate the functionality of `my` for variables that cannot otherwise be declared lexically.

Historically, that was all variables. Since 5.6, only punctuation variables cannot be declared lexically.

---

> What is "global" variable?

A global variable is a variable that can seen globally.

All package variables can be seen by any code in the interpreter, so they're all global.

Or are they? To see them from other packages, you need to qualify them. Are `$x` and `$Foo::x` the same variable?

To some, global variables refers to the set of package variables you can use unqualified. It means that `package` changes the set of global variables. And since the `package` directive is usually used on a file-basis, that means file-level lexicals are also effectively global by this definition. And they are indeed called that sometimes.

But if the `package` changes the set of variables that are global, then they're not really global, are they? So think some people, which only consider punctuation variables (e.g. `$_`) and the few named variables that can be used unqualified from anywhere (`*::STDOUT`) to be global.

In short, it's a pretty useless term.

---

> Is it possible to add the my scoped variables in @EXPORT array and use it in another packages?

No. `@EXPORT` is used by Exporter. Exporter would not be able to find anything but package symbols (since files are compiled in fresh lexical scopes), so `@EXPORT` must only contain package symbols.

Comment: 'ikegami' : Basically 'local' and 'my' are same except for scope. 'my' cannot be accessed as you shown in the foo() but local works there. Are there any real practical scenarios where we use 'local'

Comment: why local is called dynamic scoping

Comment: No, that's completely wrong. Only symbols have scopes, and there's no such thing as a local var. As I already said, `local $_;`, cause you can't do `my $_;`

Comment: Cause that's a name for what it does if you ignore the fact that variable doesn't stop existing after `local`'s scope is exited.

Comment: @Nitesh There are many real, practical scenarios where you can use `local`. A common example is [reading a file into a scalar](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=287647).

Comment: So "global" actually means "defined in the current package", right?

Comment: @U. Windl No. See update.

Answer (score 7):

Here's what I found out about variable scopes:

`my` declarations are pretty clear and straightforward if used inside blocks. If used in main outside any block, they are a bit different though, meaning that a `my` variable declared outside a block is visible even inside functions called from anywhere inside the same file as long as these functions are defined within the same file. If declared inside a block, though, they are not visible to functions even if called from the same block. All `my` variables seem to live on the stack. And: you cannot localize them with `local`.

`our` variables live on the heap. Even if you have a `my` variable by the same name, the our variable can still be accessed through `${'var'}`, which looks up a variable of that name in the symbol table and dereferences it. `my` variables, on the other hand, have not symbol table entries.

`local` variables seem to me like a relic from former Perl versions. They are just re-assignments to global (`our`) variables with block scope and resume their former values after the block terminates.  I can see no real sense in using them.

My little program below shows all this, and it shows how badly a declared() test is missing, beyond the well-known defined() test, to identify undeclared variables as such.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 use strict;

 ### This is about variable scoping with my, our and local
 my $fsv = "file scope";                 # visible for all code in this file
 our $gsv = "global scope";              # not different from my $fsv, except in packages
 our $lsv = "global";                    # global scope, but localized in subsequent block

 {
    my $bsv = "lex scope";               # visible only inside this block, not even in subs called from here
    $gsv = "visible everywhere";
    local $lsv = "global, but localized val";

    print "This is variable \$bsv with value $bsv inside block\n";
    print "This is variable \$fsv with value $fsv inside block\n";
    print "This is variable \$lsv with value $lsv inside block\n\n";
    print_vars("calledfromblock");
 }

 print_vars("calledfromoutside");


 no strict 'vars';                       # needed if testing variable for declaredness rather than definedness
 if ( defined $bsv ) {
    print "\$bsv as defined outside braces: $bsv\n"
 } else {
    print "\$bsv not defined outside braces\n";
 }
 print "This is variable \$lsv with value $lsv outside block\n";
 # use strict 'vars';                    # no strict 'vars' effective even in sub print_vars unless switched back on

 sub print_vars
 {
    my $whence = shift;
    my $gsv = "my variable";
    no strict 'refs';                    # needed to access the global var $gsv using ${'gsv'} despite the my declaration

    if ( $whence eq "calledfromblock" ) {
       print "\t print_vars called from within the block:\n";
       ( defined $bsv )     ? print "\$bsv is $bsv inside sub\n"     : print "\$bsv not defined inside sub\n";
       ( defined $fsv )     ? print "\$fsv is $fsv inside sub\n"     : print "\$fsv not defined inside sub\n";
       ( defined ${'gsv'} ) ? print "\$gsv is ${'gsv'} inside sub\n" : print "\$gsv not defined inside sub\n";
       ( defined ${'lsv'} ) ? print "\$lsv is ${'lsv'} inside sub\n" : print "\$lsv not defined inside sub\n";
    } else {
       print "\t print_vars called from outside the block:\n";
       ( defined $bsv ) ? print "\$bsv is $bsv inside sub\n" : print "\$bsv not defined inside sub\n";
       ( defined $fsv ) ? print "\$fsv is $fsv inside sub\n" : print "\$fsv not defined inside sub\n";
       ( defined $gsv ) ? print "\$gsv is $gsv inside sub\n" : print "\$gsv not defined inside sub\n";
       ( defined $lsv ) ? print "\$lsv is $lsv inside sub\n" : print "\$lsv not defined inside sub\n";
    }
    print "\n";
 }
```

Comment: That was a useful answer with nice explanatory code. I've upvoted and edited it to remove line numbers from the program code, fix mis-spellings, add add code formatting for Perl keywords.

Comment: I think "our variables live on the heap" is confusing, because all variable values live on the heap. Maybe explain in a better way.

Comment: I don't remember 'local' that way at all.  Dynamic scoping was a Big Deal in early perl, but people from an ALGOL/C backgrounds got confused.  LISP people didn't.  This lead to the introduction of 'my' (staticly scoped) variables.  Calling 'local' a relic is to misunderstand that perl has (had?) more in common with LISP than C.  But it's been decades, so there's that.

Answer (score 6):

There are two kinds of variables, lexically scoped and globally scoped.

In Perl before version 5, there was only globally scoped.  These variables are the package variables.  These variables are available everywhere in the program if you use the package prefix.

The `local` keyword was introduced to provide a way to alter the value of one of these package global variables inside a limited scope, such as inside one subroutine.  It will save the old value on a stack when entering the scope with the `local` statement, and upon exiting, it will restore the old value.  These are still package globals, which means that they are still available everywhere.  If you are inside a scope with a `local` variable, and you call a subroutine, that variable is still visible inside that subroutine.

The `my` keyword was introduced in version 5, and provides lexically scoped variables.  These variables only exist inside the scope where they are declared.  This means that if you call a subroutine, that `my` variable is not visible.  Upon exiting a scope, the `my` variables simply go away.  You should prefer to use `my` variables when possible, because you do not want your variables to be visible inside subroutines that you call.  You cannot use these type of variables in the `@EXPORT` list because these variables are not visible outside of their scope.

Finally, the `our` keyword is a combination of both, in that it gives you a variable that is a package global, but that variable is lexically scoped.  This means it will be available anywhere in the program, but at the end of the enclosing block, you cannot refer to that variable any more.

Comment: why local is called dynamic scoping

Comment: The scope of a `local` variable depends on what happens at run-time.  The variable's scope begins at the line with `local` and ends at the end of the enclosing block, but that variable's scope also includes all of the subroutines that are called in between.  To contrast, a `my` variable has a static scope, because it does not change based on what happens at run-time.

Comment: please add example

Answer (score 5):

###Example 1:

```
sub mess_with_foo {
    $foo=0;
}

sub myfunc {
    my $foo=20;
    mess_with_foo();
    print $foo;
}
myfunc();
```

###Example 2:

```
sub mess_with_foo {
    $foo=0;
}

sub myfunc {
    local $foo=20;
    mess_with_foo();
    print $foo;
}
myfunc();
```

**Example 1** prints `20` because `mess_with_foo()` could not see `my $foo`. It could not change it.  `my $foo` can only be seen in its scope of `myfunc()`.

**Example 2**  prints `0` because `mess_with_foo()` can see `my $foo` and change it. `local $foo` can be seen in its scope of `myfunc()` AND in the scope of any function called from within its scope of `myfunc()`.

That's the only difference. Neither `my $foo` nor `local $foo` will be seen outside of their scope of `myfunc()`.