# Package Variable in Perl not in "scope"?

Tags: perl, perlvar

I was looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19100106/368630), and while I was playing around, I came across this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
# use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

{
    our $foo = "bar";
    say "Foo = $foo";
}

say "Foo = $foo";  # This is line #12
```

Yes, I do have `use warnings;` turned off...

When I run this, I get:

```
Variable "$foo" is not imported at ./test.pl line 12.
Global symbol "$foo" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 12.
Execution of ./test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Hmmm... I get the same "*Variable "$foo" is not imported at ./test.pl line 12.*" error if I had done `my $foo = "bar";`. I would understand this when I use `my` because there is no variable `$foo` once we leave the block. But, `our` variables are suppose to be package scope. I could understand how `$foo` might not have a value at that point, but this?

Also, what does the "*Variable "$foo" is not imported at ./test.pl line 12.*" mean? I understand packages and importing, but there's only a single package here, `main`. `$foo` should be in the `main` package. It doesn't need to be imported.

What is going on with my package variable that doesn't seem to be in the package after it falls out of scope?

---

### Addendum

> So if you used `$::foo`, or created another alias with `our $foo;` again, your program would work as expected. [cmj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22201777/368630)

Let's try this...

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
# use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

{
    our $foo = "bar";
    say "Foo = $foo";
}

our $foo;          # Redeclared
say "Foo = $foo";  # This is line #12
```

Now, this prints out:

```
bar
bar
```

As everyone who answered  pointed out, `our` merely makes an *alias* to the package variable of the same name, and it's *lexically* scoped. That means once the alias goes out of scope, so did my ability to access the value of `$main::foo` with `$foo`. That's something I never realized before.

However, as cjm pointed out, redeclaring `our $foo;` restores the alias, and the already existing `$main::foo` is aliased back to a new `$foo`. When I redeclare `our $foo;`, the value of `$foo` is *restored*.

It's one of the things about `our` variables that can be so confusing. You see a declaration `our $foo;`, and suddenly not only does that variable exist, but it has a mysterious value. You have to search the program to see where that value could have come from.

Comment: Great question. I had a similar problem. I was hoping `eval "$::var=1"; say $var` would work.. But I still had to do `our $var` before `say`..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Our](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html) declares a lexical alias to a package variable.  This means that it's scoped just like `my`.  The difference is that it's backed by a package variable, so the variable doesn't go away when you exit the scope.  Only the alias goes away.

So if you used `$::foo`, or created another alias with `our $foo` again, your program would work as expected.

Comment: ...or move `our $foo;` out of the curlies, or use `use vars qw( $foo );`

Comment: @ikegami, yes, TIMTOWTDI.

Comment: @ikegami Except I purposefully put the our declaration inside the block, so it wouldn't be in a limited scope just to see what happens.

Comment: I never realized that `our` merely makes an alias to the package variable, and that alias is _lexically scoped_. Now, that I think of it, it makes perfect sense in the way Perl compiler would have to work. See my addendum.

Comment: No, it doesn't have to work that way. It could set a flag that tells strict to ignore the variable (like it does for imported variables). `our $var` would them be equivalent to `use vars qw( $var );`

Comment: An interesting consequence is this: `package Foo; our $xxx = 42; package Bar; say $xxx;` — so within package Bar, the `$xxx` variable is still available, and still an alias for a variable within the Foo package.

Answer (score 2):

[Our](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html) does not indicate package scope.

> An our declaration declares an alias for a package variable that will
>   be visible across its entire lexical scope, even across package
>   boundaries.

This means that when the lexical scope of the block that declared it ends, it falls out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

> *what does the "Variable "$foo" is not imported at ./test.pl line 12." mean?*

perldiag says:

> With "use strict" in effect, you referred to a global variable
>   that you apparently thought was imported from another module, because
>   something else of the same name (usually a subroutine) is exported by
>   that module.  It usually means you put the wrong funny character on the
>   front of your variable.

That makes no sense since you didn't import anything. It shouldn't be emitted by your code. Perl's trying to be helpful in diagnosing the strict error, but got it wrong. Ignore the warning.

---

> *But, our variables are suppose to be package scope*

That's not true. `our` creates a lexical variable just like `my`. That variable is aliased to the package variable with the same name.

```
package Foo;
our $x;         # Equivalent to: alias my $x = $Foo::x;
$Foo::x = 123;
package Bar;
$Bar::x = 456;
print("$x\n");  # 123
```

(`alias` is provided by Data::Alias.)