# In Perl, how do I extract out the declaration of variables into a wrapper script?

Tags: perl, wrapper

## Background

I have a perl script, called main.pl that is currently in several branched states on clear case like so:

Branch 1:

```
my %hash
my $variable = "a"
my $variable2 = "c"

sub codeIsOtherwiseTheSame()
....
```

Branch 2:

```
my %hash2
my $variable = "b"

sub codeIsOtherwiseTheSame()
....
```

Branch 3

```
my %hash
my $variable2 = "d"

sub codeIsOtherwiseTheSame()
....
```

Right now, each branch of the script has the same code.  The only differences are the kind of variables that are declared and what their initialized value is. What I want to do is extract these differing variables out to a wrapper script (for each variation) so that the main script does not have to be changed. I am doing this because several users will be using this script, but have only minor differences based on their use case. Thus I want each kind of user to have their own simplified interface.  At the same time, I want the main script to still be aware of these variable once it is called.  Below is an example of what I want:

## Desired Solution

Wrapper Script 1:

```
 my %hash;
 my $variable = "a";
 my $variable2 = "c";
 system("main.pl");
```

Wrapper Script 2:

```
 my %hash2;
 my $variable = "b";
 system("main.pl");
```

Wrapper Script  3:

```
my %hash;
my $variable2 = "d";
system("main.pl");
```

Main.pl

```
sub codeIsOtherwiseTheSame()
```

## Question

How do I extract out a wrapper script to obtain the organization and behavior I want above?

Comment: system() spawns a new process and any variables in the calling code are therefore inaccessible.  To do what you want, you would have to put the variables into the environment before spawning.  $ENV{variable} = "a"; etc.  But the right way to do this kind of thing is with a module as choroba described.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extract the common code into a module, not a script. Save it as e.g. `MyCommon.pm`.
Export a function from the module that does what you need:

```
package MyCommon;
use Exporter qw{ import };
our @EXPORT = qw{ common_code };

sub common_code {
    my ($var1, $var2) = @_;
    # Common code goes here...
}
```

Then, in various scripts, write

```
use MyCommon qw{ common_code };

common_code('a', 'b');  # <- insert the specific values here.
```

There are more advanced ways, e.g. you can use "object orientation": construct an object from the specific values, then run a method that implements the common code - but for simple use cases, you probably don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

Desired behavior for simple case as yours can be achieved with with [required](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) function of perl

Put common code in a file, for example **common.inc** end the file with `1;` (requirement for modules and include files)

```
sub commonFunction {
    my $data = shift;

    print "DATA: $data\n";
}

1;
```

Copy/move **common.inc** file into one of **@INC** directory (probably **site** directory best fit for this purpose).

Check your perl **@INC** configuration setting with following command

```
perl -e "print qw(@INC)"
```

Now you can *reuse* **common.inc** file in your *user interface* script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

require 'common.inc';

my $a = 7;

commonFunction($a);
```

Already was suggested to place the common code which will be reused multiple times  in form of **.pm** module.

By doing so you gain more control what functions/variables are visible (exported) to avoid *namespace* clash/collision [the modules can have functions/variables with same name].

Short [tutorial](https://www.perltutorial.org/perl-module/) how to create a module is available. Next natural step will be [OOP programming](https://www.perltutorial.org/perl-oop/).

Book: [Object Oriented Perl](https://www.manning.com/books/object-oriented-perl)

[perlootut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html), [Writing perl modules](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_modules.htm), Chapter [Object Oriented Perl](https://blob.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/3145_Chap11.pdf)

Comment: Only use `require`/`use` for files with a `package`. Use `do` for files without. But you really shouldn't have such files. This is a model that was supplanted by modules over 20 years ago!

Comment: @ ikegami - Documentation for **do** states _It also differs in that code evaluated with 'do FILE' cannot see lexicals in the enclosing scope; 'eval STRING' does._. You should provide a sample code to prove your point. A test run of a script demonstrated that a variable from _external_ script is not accessible on _inner_ script.

Comment: The documentation is 100% correct. Files included via `do`, `require` or `use` can't access lexicals in the scope in which the `do`/`require`/`use` is located. [Demonstration](https://pastebin.com/KzqinAzK) I'm not sure what that has to do with anything.

Comment: As for why `do` is more appropriate, see how it uses `%INC` compared to `require`.

Comment: I assume that the author of the question will use variables from _outer_ script in _inner_ common code. In case of **do** they are not accessible.

Comment: If that's what you believe, then your solution doesn't work. Like I said and proved above, they're not accessible when using `require` either. In both cases, they would need to be passed as arguments. Only `eval` allows you to access the surrounding scope (and even then, there are limits).

Comment: @ikegami - here I must agree with you. In my original test I have passed arguments and used them in code - it works fine. But then when you referred to **do** as I never used this approach I went right to read documentation. The quote I referred to earlier been caught by my eye -- and I mentioned it. A few seconds ago I run a quick test and indeed **require** hides global scope variables - it can be looked as an advantage and from other point a disadvantage. But to pass variables is more correct approach (only module might have global variable - Yahoo had such variable to extract stock quotes)

Comment: It hides *lexical* vars. Global vars, by definition, are visible everywhere

Comment: Ok, you caught me here -- I never looked before definition of lexical variable (any variable declared with **my**). Then could you demonstrate what would be **global** variable in perl?

Comment: Ok, I found that only **Package** variables can have global scope -- hmm, different from C,C++. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100106/local-and-global-variables-in-perl]

Comment: "_different from C,C++_" ... yeah ... go figure.  I can't help it but add: this post is a terrible advice in this day. It's all told in the very first comment, "_This is a model that was supplanted by modules over 20 years ago_".  One can't really hash out all the whys in comments but using modules is just (far) better.  (In fact, simply having "common code" be a full program that's called with suitable arguments would also be better in this case.)