# In Perl, do "$a" and "$b" have any special use outside of the sort() function?

Tags: perl, global-variables, lexical-scope

I asked a question about the use of "$a" and "$b" in Perl's `sort()` function the other day:

[What exactly are "$a" and "$b" in Perl's "sort()" function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127617/what-exactly-are-a-and-b-in-perls-sort-function)

I now have a follow up question.  Are "$a" and "$b" only used by `sort()` or is there any other Perl function that takes advantage of these special global variables?

Or even if no other function uses them, are there any situations outside of `sort()` that you would use "$a" or "$b"?

### Edit:

To clarify:

In short, the question is can "$a" and "$b" be used by something other than `sort()`?

I am just curious to see what other situations they can be used in.  I have never seen "$a" or "$b" used by anything else and was wondering have any other special use outside of `sort()`.

Comment: they're not global variables. they're just defacto standard names for the arguments passed into a sort function's callback.

Comment: @MarcB: the sort function's callback doesn't get passed anything (unless it has a `$$` prototype, in which case it uses `$_[0]` and `$_[1]` and *not* `$a` and `$b`).  They are indeed (package) global variables.

Comment: something funny: `my ($a, $b); print Dumper [ sort { $a <=> $b } map rand(10), 0..9 ]`

Comment: @salva `Can't use "my $a" in sort comparison` is funny?

Comment: yes, it is just `warnings` (and `strict`) that removes all the fun from perl!

Comment: @salva I disagree. And that is not a warning that comes from `strict`or `warnings`.

Comment: @TLP: so, where does it comes from?

Comment: @salva I just confirmed that even without `strict` or `warnings` the error still occurs.  I don't know where the error comes from, but it definitely is not from `strict` or `warnings`.

Comment: @tjwrona1992: Not in my perl! `$ perl -MData::Dumper -E 'my ($a, $b); print Dumper [ sort { $a <=> $b } map rand(10), 0..9 ]`

Comment: @salva Hmm that is strange, it could be a difference in Perl versions.  What version of Perl are you running?  I am running v5.16.3.

Comment: @tjwrona1992: 5.20.0 (Ubuntu 14.10)

Comment: @tjwrona1992: It seems it was a bug that become fixed on 5.18.0... so, doubly funny!

Comment: @salva: Hmm, very interesting. I wonder what would happen if you tried to declare $a and $b as lexicals in the scope of a `sort` without using `warnings` or `strict`.  Would it clobber your locally defined $a and $b, or would it preserve them and restore their values when the `sort` completes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *can "$a" and "$b" be used by something other than `sort()`?*

As it has already been explained, there's nothing special about `$a` and `$b` (except that they are predeclared). Asking if an ordinary variable can be used by some thing other than one function makes no sense. Here is `$a` being used by something that isn't `sort`:

```
 $ perl -E'$a=123; say $a;'
 123
```

That said, it's not a very good idea to do so. It's best to [use lexical variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20890822/589924), and declaring `$a` or `$b` as lexical variables will render them unavailable to use in `sort` (or in List::Util's functions) without an overriding `our ($a,$b);`.

```
$ perl -e'sub foo { my ($a) = @_; "..."; sort { $a cmp $b } @a; "..." }'
Can't use "my $a" in sort comparison at -e line 1.
```

Comment: I guess the question then becomes is it considered bad coding practice to use $a or $b for something other than `sort()`?

Comment: Yeah. Added a bit more to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Other non-built-in functions, such as List::Util::reduce, use them too.

Could you explain why you are asking, though?  I feel like you are looking for something bigger than that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

$a and $b are the names the sort function assigns to the two elements it is comparing, which are the parameters it assigns to the "compare()" user-supplied callback function.

You can think using the "$a", "$b" logic in any function you design, to which you provide a function as a parameter, and provide two (or more) arguments to that function...

Hope I was clear enough...

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no, they're not special except in the context of `sort`".  However, I did have occasion to use them outside of a `sort` routine recently, which is kind of germane to your question.

I used `$a` and `$b` directly in order to utilize my `sort` function for a single comparison.  I scoped them with `local` and used a `do` block to contain the scope:

```
my $cmp = do {
    local $a = $summary->{current_version};
    local $b = $latest_version_on_usb;
    cmp_version();
};
```

`cmp_version` is a subroutine designed to be used with `sort`, so, normally its use looks like this:

```
my @sorted_versions = sort cmp_version @old_versions;
```

Because `cmp_version` knows it will be called by `sort`, it does all of its work on `$a` and `$b` internally.

The fact that I wanted to re-use my sort subroutine in a non-sorting context (I just wanted the output of a single "`$foo cmp_version $bar`" comparison as if `cmp_version` was a real operator like `<=>` or `cmp` ) is what prompted this.  It's the only reason I can think of to use `$a` and `$b` unless it's in a `sort` block or subroutine--the fact that they *are* special in the context of `sort` means that messing around with them outside that context could end up biting you.

Comment: Very interesting use of `$a` and `$b`.  However in this situation if `$foo` and `$bar` are objects, I feel like it would make more sense to simply overload the `<=>` operator to compare versions, that way you could directly use `<=>` like so: `$foo <=> $bar` and get the results you're looking for.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 That would be a great way to go, in that case.  In mine, as it happens, they're just hashes with version information--$foo->{major}, $foo->{minor}, $foo->{update}, and $foo->{rc}.  I needed a special sort  because 1.0.0 is actually *after* 1.0.0rc10--you do several release candidates before deciding "this is the actual 1.0.0".  Kind of a weird case, and I guess it made sense that it generated a weird code situation :).

Comment: In that case, if you want to get really fancy you could make the hashes store version objects instead of simple strings and the version class could have `<=>` overloaded!  Then you could compare `$foo->{major} <=> $bar->{major}`. :)