# Appending consecutive numbers to file names

Tags: for-loop, awk, sed

I have a list of files like

```
Ortho234.phy
Ortho671.phy
Ortho880.phy and so on
```

I would like to rename them for an array job to

```
Ortho234.1.phy
Ortho671.2.phy
Ortho880.3.phy
```

I tried this but this replaces and just names the file as 1.phy, 2.phy and so on.

```
 a=1
 for i in *.phy; do
     new=$(printf "%04d.phy" "$a") 
     mv -- "$i" "$new"
     let a=a+1
 done
```

Comment: `i` is your filename and you aren't using it.

Comment: Personally I feel you have an x<->y problem as you have gained no benefit by renaming the files and would better off asking for help with your actual array problem.  Files are still in the same order as they were prior to adding the new numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any one of the following commands will do your job

> ```
> c=0 rename 's/\./sprintf(".%d.",++$ENV{c})/e' *.phy  
>
> rename 's/\./".".++$a."."/e' *.phy                  
>
> rename '$a++; s/\./.$a./e' *.phy                   
>
> n=1;for f in *.phy; do mv "$f" "${f%.*}.$n.${f##*.}"; n=$((n+1)); done
> ```

**Either**

> It executes the `perl s///` expression, and performs the rename from the
>   original to the replaced string. In the replacement string I use
>   `sprintf` to format the name, where I use the environment variable `c`as
>   the counter

```
$ touch Ortho234.phy  Ortho671.phy  Ortho880.phy

$ ls *.phy -1
Ortho234.phy
Ortho671.phy
Ortho880.phy

$ c=0 rename 's/\./sprintf(".%d.",++$ENV{c})/e' *.phy

$ ls *.phy -1
Ortho234.1.phy
Ortho671.2.phy
Ortho880.3.phy
```

**OR**

```
$ touch Ortho234.phy  Ortho671.phy  Ortho880.phy

$ ls *.phy -1
Ortho234.phy  
Ortho671.phy  
Ortho880.phy

$ n=1;for f in *.phy; do mv "$f" "${f%.*}.$n.${f##*.}"; n=$((n+1)); done

$ ls *.phy -1
Ortho234.1.phy  
Ortho671.2.phy  
Ortho880.3.phy
```

**OR**

```
$ touch Ortho234.phy  Ortho671.phy  Ortho880.phy

$ ls *.phy -1
Ortho234.phy
Ortho671.phy
Ortho880.phy

$ rename 's/\./".".++$a."."/e' *.phy

$ ls *.phy -1
Ortho234.1.phy
Ortho671.2.phy
Ortho880.3.phy
```

**OR**

```
$ touch Ortho234.phy  Ortho671.phy  Ortho880.phy

$ ls *.phy -1
Ortho234.phy
Ortho671.phy
Ortho880.phy

$ rename '$a++; s/\./.$a./e' *.phy

$ ls *.phy -1
Ortho234.1.phy
Ortho671.2.phy
Ortho880.3.phy
```

Comment: I pick door number 2!  (Portability++) ... And I'll upvote if you remove the [ParsingLS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) option. :-)

Comment: can also use `rename 's/\./".".++$a."."/e' *.phy` or `rename '$a++; s/\./".$a."/e' *.phy`, takes advantage of [sort global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127617/what-exactly-are-a-and-b-in-perls-sort-function)

Comment: @Sundeep: Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: just realized that `e` is not needed for 2nd suggestion, `rename '$a++; s/\./.$a./' *.phy`

Comment: what does e stand for the expression     's/\./".".++$a."."/e'   ? If I am not getting it wrong "." before and after ++$a is a string concatenate operator of perl ?

Comment: @Vicky : `e` modifier enables evaluation in the substitution

Comment: @AkshayHegde: thanks but do you have a link or a document where I can read about that more ? also if you could confirm on my second part  "If I am not getting it wrong "." before and after ++$a is a string concatenate operator of perl ? " in my post earlier , thanks in advance

Comment: @Vicky: Here we are searching for `.` and replacing with `.<number>.` , in first example `rename 's/\./".".++$a."."/e' *.phy` yes its `".".`<- this dot is for string concatenation, that is `"." <concatenation operator .><number ++$a><concatenation operator .>"."`.  `"."` is just string but next dot without quote is concatenation operator, I hope its clear now

Comment: @Vicky : please follow this link http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1007141

Comment: Thanks Akshay but unfortunately this rename syntax seems to be not supported on my bash version. I am using 4.1.11. Do you know which bash version supports it ?

Comment: @Vicky: This is my rename version `rename --version` gives
`/usr/bin/rename using File::Rename version 0.20`

Comment: @AkshayHegde: rename --version  gives me     rename from util-linux 2.21.2

Comment: @Akshay: there is no error the command just runs quietly and when I check the output I don't the the files renamed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136272/discussion-between-akshay-hegde-and-vicky).

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
a=1
for i in *.phy; do
filepart=$(echo $i | sed 's/.phy//g')
new=$(printf "%s.%d.phy" "$filepart" "$a")
mv -- "$i" "$new"
let a=a+1
done
```

filepart is filename, without the extension.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F\. '{print $1"."NR"."$2}' file

Ortho234.1.phy
Ortho671.2.phy
Ortho880.3.phy
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` command is also help in getting the desired output. `NR` gives the line number and split the input on `.` and rewrite the array as per the needed like following

```
awk '{split($0,a,"."); print a[1]"."NR"."a[2]}' file
```

file is the input file containing the following values

```
Ortho234.phy
Ortho671.phy
Ortho880.phy
```

Comment: awk could read Input_file itself no need to use cat Input_file | awk .... command then. It is usually called UUOC(Useless use of cat command).