# Perl script editing a CSV file

Tags: arrays, perl, csv

I have a CSV input file (input.csv) with numbers looking like:

```
1.34,7.56,4.57,6.7,4.9, 3.4,5.7,5.4,........
```

I want to edit the file and insert numbers and a colon between fields like;

```
1:1.34 2:7.56 3:4.57 4:6.7 5:4.9 6:3.4 7:5.7 8:5.4..........
```

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#Opening the CSV file

my $csv_file = "input.csv";

open (my $fh, "<", $csv_file) or die "Cannot open '$csv_file': $! ";

#parsing

while (my $lines = <$fh> ) {

  chomp $lines;

  my @features = split (',', $lines);
  print "$lines \n";
} 

#inserting numbers

for ( my $x = 1; $x <= 1371; $x++ ){
  print $x . ":" . $features[$x-1];
}
```

I get an error:
    Global symbol "@features" requires explicit package name at script_T.pl line 23.

Comment: It would help everybody to read your code if you laid it out more neatly. I have done it for you this time. In the future please try to post something nicer

Comment: Hi Borodin, My apology, am just learning Perl and i have little experience in programming so i know the script is rusty, but i will improve. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This can be done neatly with `split`, `map` and `join`, like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <> ) {
  my @fields = split /\s*,\s*/;
  print join ' ', map "$_:$fields[$_-1]", 1 .. @fields;
}
```

**output**

```
1:1.34 2:7.56 3:4.57 4:6.7 5:4.9 6:3.4 7:5.7 8:5.4 9:........
```

The program expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line, like this

```
./count_fields.pl input.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `@features` before the while loop:

```
my @features;
while (my $lines = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $lines;
    @features = split (',', $lines);
    print "$lines \n";

    for(my $x=1; $x <=1371 ; $x++){
        print $x .":".$features[$x-1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have declared @features array within while block using "my" which makes it available only within the block. Declare it before while.
To know more about scope in perl, read

[Variable Scoping in Perl: the basics](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=66677)

[what-is-the-difference-between-my-and-our-in-perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845060/what-is-the-difference-between-my-and-our-in-perl)